# Proof by induction for recursive sequence $a_n =a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} + a_{\lceil n/2 \rceil} +3n +1$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

I have to proof the following

> $$n\leq 2^k \Rightarrow a_n \leq 3 \cdot k2^k +4\cdot 2^k -1 $$
> for all $n,k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
>
> given the running time for a sorting algorithm that can be described recursively by $a_1 =3$ and $$a_n =a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} + a_{\lceil n/2 \rceil} +3n +1,  \quad  n\geq 2$$

**My answer:**
It should be possible to show this by strong induction.

$P(n):$ when $n\leq2^k$ the following holds $a_n \leq 3 \cdot k2^k +4\cdot 2^k -1$

*Base step*

$$P(1): 1 \leq 2^k \Rightarrow a_1 =3 \leq 3 \cdot k2^k +4\cdot 2^k -1 \quad \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$

*Inductive step:* Assume $P(1)...P(n)$ is true. We want to show that $P(n+1)$ is also true

$$ P(n+1): n+1 \leq 2^k \Rightarrow a_{n+1} = a_{\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor} + a_{\left\lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil} +3(n+1) + 1  $$

Let $\frac{n+1}{2}=m$

$$ n+1 \leq 2^k \Rightarrow a_{n+1} = a_{\left\lfloor m \right\rfloor} + a_{\left\lceil m \right\rceil} +3n+4  $$

... and this is where I am stuck. How do I use $a_{\left\lfloor m \right\rfloor} + a_{\left\lceil m \right\rceil}$?

Comment: The hypothesis "when $n\leq2^k$ the following holds $a_n \leq 3 \cdot k2^k +4\cdot 2^k -1$" **depends on $k$**, not on $n$. Hence you should call it $P(k)$, not $P(n)$, then show that $P(0)$ holds, then show that $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ for every $k\geqslant0$. Please explain what is not direct in all this.

Comment: Assume $k\ge 1$. If $n+1\le 2^k$ then $m\le 2^{k-1}<2^k$ so $\lfloor m \rfloor \le \lceil m \rceil\le 2^k$ so you can apply inductive hypothesis to both of them. If $k=0$ things are rather trivial;

Comment: When you have floors and ceilings like this, I would separately consider the cases of even and odd n.

Comment: @Did I've shown that $P(1)$ holds. Now I just need to show that $P(k+1)$ is true. When writing it in I get $ n\leq 2^{k+1} \Rightarrow a_n \leq 3 (k+1) 2^{k+1} + 4 \cdot 2^{k+1} -1$. But isn't that what I am supposed to show? Then there isn't more to it?

Comment: Sorry but from your last comment it is impossible to know what you did, what you showed, what you didn't show. If you think you have a valid proof then post it and we will be able to talk concretely.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to prove that $a_n$ is an increasing function. Also what you want to prove is only related to $2^k$, so you want to prove the statement for that and an induction on $k$ is enough, and the floor or ceiling function won't bother you at all.